# how to redirect to next page in ajax success block

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, redirect

I want to redirect to admin_dashboard page in ajax.I call a function in button tag and want to redirect to next page in success response.value gets deleted perfectly but my problem is "Deleted Successfully" message is not returned and not redirect to admin_dashboard.php page. instaed of '1' in function I used dynamic valued.for sample I used '1'   myFunction(1).I caught an error in console.
  [image]

HTML

```
<button style="margin-left:10px;" name="delete" onclick="myFunction(1);">Delete</button>
```

Script

```
function myFunction(del) {

    var rmvfile = del;

    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete the file?") == true) {
        if (del != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'query9.php',
                data: {
                    rmvfile: rmvfile
                },
                success: function(msg) {
                    window.location.href = 'admin_dashboard.php';
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

my php query page

```
 <?php
 include "config.php";
 $s=$_POST['rmvfile'];  
 $del="delete from requirement where req_id='$s'";
 if($del1=mysql_query($del))
 {
     echo 'Deleted Successfully';
 }
```

Comment: replace your `window.location.href = 'admin_dashboard.php';` with `window.open('admin_dashboard.php','_self');`

Comment: window.open('admin_dashboard.php'); not working

Comment: _self is aldo not working.Is any other way to do this

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions. Use instead e.g. PDO.

Comment: if it doesn't work, may be the ajax is not `success`. there could be an `error` in the process (jus like what @HenriSchellingerhout says). so you have to trap the `errors` too.

Comment: is any way to trap it

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi, why `window.location.href` is not working ?
Why to replace it wint `window.open()` ?

Comment: after `success : function (){},` add this line `error : function (a){alert(a.responseText+"|"+a.statusText)}`. DONT FORGET THE COMMA AFTER `success` function

Comment: @user3386779, you need to debug whether your code flow is reaching in success callback? I dont think it is..

Comment: @user3386779 open your browser console and check for error reports.

Comment: It does the same thing @RayonDabre ! :D 
I didn't say it doesn't work

Comment: error function return '|error' message

Comment: it surely you have an error in your process! rechek your php process!

Comment: @user3386779 give us your `config.php`. I suggest you to use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` functions

Comment: <?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
$db_found = mysql_select_db(dam_box);
if ($db_found) {
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
}

?>

Comment: I already did the same process without redirecting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88858/discussion-between-oki-erie-rinaldi-and-user3386779).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88868/discussion-between-user3386779-and-oki-erie-rinaldi).

Answer (score -1):

Try below code in your php script:

```
<?php
 include "config.php";
 $s=$_POST['rmvfile'];  
 $del="delete from requirement where req_id='$s'";
 if( mysql_query($del) )
{
echo 'Deleted Successfully';
 }
```

Comment: what you changed it it?

Comment: I chaged this if($del1=mysql_query($del))  this if( mysql_query($del) ) - Coz you are making an assignment here and not the check.

Comment: any other way to fix it

Comment: are you seeing any javascript error in console. If so, can you please share that error. Or you have any other hint?

Comment: Looks like the js error is preventing the browser to redirect to "admin_dashboard.php". Correct your javascript error that your are seeing n the console and try again.